# Bitcoin purchases by country

Tags: address, adoption

I'm interested in getting data on bitcoin adoption by country. Is there a way of mapping bitcoin addresses to countries of origination?

Comment: Can't you tell what IP address transactions and other Bitcoin operations (e.g. creating a new address) come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nate is right.  But there is this tool:

http://fiatleak.com/

which can help you see a particular currency's exchanges in and out of Bitcoin.

Euro, USD and Yuan are usually the most predominant.

It could be somewhat helpful, it is open and javascript based so you can see how it works.

That could possibly give you additional ideas on solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nate's answer is true about transactions generally, although companies like Chainalysis use sophisticated software and methods to try to find sources of transactions.

This may not be what you are looking for, but if you could do with geolocated non-hidden full node data, then I've written an open-access academic paper on Bitcoin full node data [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8), and the data is in the [Electronic Supplements](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8/MediaObjects/11187_2019_309_MOESM1_ESM.xlsx). I explain in the [Appendix](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8#appendices) how I get and prepare the data if you need more fine-grained analyses. The data is country-year from 2014-2018.

PS: The data includes Bitcoin merchant data worldwide too. Please do cite the paper after use. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No. Bitcoin addresses are designed to be anonymous and convey no information about the person or computer that generated them.

If you could somehow identify the owners of some addresses, then by observing transactions going to or from those addresses, you might be able to infer things about their counterparties. Then again, you might not. It certainly seems unlikely you'll get any useful large-scale statistics that way.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, bitcoin is extremely stealthy and if your incidental exposure address link is not correct